# i have my value as 2018-05-03 11:02:00 in mysql i want to pass this in my where condition using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

In my table 'time' data is present on 2018-05-03 11:02:00 this datetime. So I want to get the data by passing this datetime.

Here is my code:

```
$query1=$this->db->query("SELECT sum(count) As total, sum(status) As 
is_completed FROM `tasks` WHERE `staff_id` = '$datas[$i]' AND `time` > 
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
```

This code showing no results but there is a data present on this datetime. how 
can i pass this datetime as where condition

Comment: can anyone tell the solution

Comment: are you using mysqli or PDO for query

Comment: iam using query

Comment: If I do [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/324478/1) it works. What's not working for you? Is it just a matter that you're not passing a valid staff id ?

Comment: ok let me query it on the sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `CUR_DATE()` to `NOW()`

```
$query1=$this->db->query("SELECT sum(count) As total, sum(status) As is_completed FROM `tasks` WHERE `staff_id` = '$datas[$i]' AND `time` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");
```

Answer (score 1):

`CURDATE()` returns a date only. So when you do `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`, you are returning the equivalent of **23:00:00 Yesterday**

It seems for what you are trying to do, it would be better to use `NOW()`.

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT sum(count) AS total, sum(status) AS is_completed
  FROM `tasks` WHERE `staff_id` = '$datas[$i]'
  AND `time` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Comment: it still returns the same ie values of total and is_completed as null

Comment: you can try like this:
$this->db->select('total,is_completed')->from('tasks')->where(staff_id=$datas[$i] AND 'time> DATE_SUB(NOW()'INTERVAL 1 HOUR);